# Rest Api permissions on one mailbox only in office365

Tags: office365api

I'm one of the It Administrators of our company and our developer need to approach with Rest Api to a certain mailbox on our office365
so he can get the email and the attachment within.

but for some reason i cannot see a way to limit the permissions to that specific mailbox
is there a way to limit those permissions to one mailbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, using an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).